Does powerBI table dataview mapping align the number of rows based on the lowest amount of rows from a datarole that's inserted there?
I'm a beginner to powerBI custom visual development. While trying to develop a custom line chart visual I've come across a behavior of pbi which I'm not sure about and it hinders development for me. It seems as if powerBI, when creating a table dataView mapping, aligns the number of rows of the table with the lowest amount of rows from any inserted data role.
Let's say I have 3 different data roles (columns from an excel file) defines as follows:
"dataRoles": [
        {
            "displayName": "Role A",
            "name": "roleA",
            "kind": "Grouping",
            "preferredTypes": [
                {"text": true}
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Role B",
            "name": "roleB",
            "kind": "Grouping",
            "preferredTypes": [
                {"numeric": true}
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Role C",
            "name": "roleC",
            "kind": "Grouping",
            "preferredTypes": [
                {"numeric": true}
            ]
        }]

And let's say I have the data mapping be a table defined like this:
"dataViewMappings": [
        {
            "conditions": [
                {
                    "roleA": {
                        "max": 1
                    },
                    "roleB": {
                        "max": 1
                    },
                    "roleC": {
                        "max": 1
                    }],
            "table": {
                "rows": {
                    "select": [
                        {
                            "for": {
                                "in": "roleA"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "for": {
                                "in": "roleB"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "for": {
                                "in": "roleC"
                            }
                        }
                     ]
               }


What I observed is that if I roleA and roleB have the same amount of rows, let's say 30, while roleC only has 4 rows, then (provided we drag all three excel columns/data roles to their respective spots) the table accessible from visual.ts through options.dataViews[0] will only have 4 rows - in other words the resulting table will always have it's number of rows aligned to the data role with the lowest number of rows.
Based on that I have 2 questions:

Is my guess correct and powerBI when creating a table dataView mapping aligns the number of rows based on the lowest number of rows out of all the data roles?

If yes, then is there a way to go around it? From what I read it's impossible to define 2 table dataView mappings side by side and I lack the knowledge on how to define the table differently so that it won't reduce the number of rows like this instead of filling out empty values with nulls or something like that.


I'd appreciate any help with this greatly.
Thanks in advance.
